# IMU model in gazebo

Tags: ros, imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I had installed hector gazebo plugins using the command  "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-hector-gazebo" . I want to model a working IMU.Since I am a beginner , can anyone explain the process that i must follow to create a bot model with an IMU in ROS or gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53471/imu-model-in-gazebo/) by [pranav](https://answers.ros.org/users/4061/pranav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to model a IMU in gazebo is just to insert the next code in the joint where you want to have the IMU and a gazebo topics will be published,

```
<sensor name='Vilma_IMU' type='imu'>
<pose>0 0.000000 0.5 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000</pose>
    <imu>
      <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
    </imu>
    <always_on>1</always_on>
    <update_rate>30</update_rate>
    </sensor>
```

---

Originally posted by [remlog](https://answers.ros.org/users/3008/remlog/) with karma: 66 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-05-25**:
hector_gazebo_plugins does not use the IMU sensor implemented in recent Gazebo versions. You can directly add it as a model plugin without the  tag, similar to the original gazebo_ros_imu plugin in package gazebo_plugins. hector_quadrotor_gazebo contains a urdf description that uses the IMU.